# Unable to discard the local changes in Git

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-for-windows, android-studio-2.0-beta5

I am using the Android Studio and Git is located with it. 
Path of Git in Android studio is as follows,
C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_cf76fc1621ac41ad4fe86c420ab5ff403f1808b9\cmd\git.exe

there are some local file changes when I tried to discard the changes to this file it says unable to discard the file. 
Also clicking on file and say, open containing the folder it locates the file to My Documents which is not the path of the Git.
It gives me an error and unable to discard the changes.

[image: Please find the attached error screenshot]

Git version is as follows:
Proctional Fungramming (3.0.14.0) 8e2e75b

Answer (score 1):

you can use stash option to keep your local changes and pull from git

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

if you want to completely overwrite your local changes then reset should work

```
git reset --hard
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

`git format-patch HEAD~X`

will dump the desired X commits to your patch file

then use `git apply` to use them

Comment: @codeWizard- shall i write above code in Git shell ?

Comment: I am getting the error as fatal : ambiguous argument 'HEAD~X: unknown revision or path in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions.

Comment: Yep.  And replace the x with the number of commits you need.  For example 5